# saving the login name as current user identity in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

So I'm making a asp.net login. I want the login name that people use to match an id in my SQL database. So that I can retrieve their information. But currently when I use the code below, from which I get the name of the computer I am currently on. However I would like the `user Identity to be` what they write `in` the username `textbox` at the login screen.

```
If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    Dim userName As String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
    Response.Write(userName)
End If
```

So I looked for it on net and I think it might have something to do with my web.config file. As I'm totally new to asp.net I wouldn't know. However here's a part of my Web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
        loginUrl="Login.aspx"
        protection="All"
        timeout="30"
        path="/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

so any ideas? :)

Comment: Did anything changed on IIS? And are you sure your application is using the same web.config which has above information? Or may be you want to share more of your web.config.

Comment: Did You put the mentioned part into Your web.config? Which web server You use to run the site (VS built-in, IIS ?). Do You have anything like this: authentication mode="Windows" in Your web config ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set login name using

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
```

and retrive using

```
User.Identity.Name
```

reference links, [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/860607-setting-httpcontext-current-user) and [asp.net tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs)

Comment: I did this. It still shows me the name of my computer/username of my user on my computer. Not the name i typed in the username field on my site. So far I have only been testing in visual studio, can this affect it? Other than that I'm pretty lost to why it shows me the wrong name now, because it worked fine earlier.

EDIT: actually I already had this in my code so I didn't change anything hehe

Comment: I did some tests. I tried writing   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("Xeano",
                chkPersistCookie.Checked)

but it still shows the name of my computer/username of computer. It doesn't show Xeano anywhere?

Comment: @xeano sorry for delay but have you found solution in this ? or still need help

Answer (score 0):

Use the ViewStates to maintain the Login state of the user.

Comment: saving login info in viewstate is bad i think

Comment: If he only stores username AND signs the ViewState, that could be not so a bad idea

Comment: @djechelon viewstate will be lost as user navigates to further next pages.